# Applying a rule on how to increment an enum

Tags: c++, enums, increment, rule

Is there a way to change how an enum sets the values of its constants? Normally it's incrementing by one but I want to apply an other rule. In PAWN this would work

```
enum (<<=1) {
 a = 1,//0b001
 b,//0b010
 c//0b100
}
```

Is there a way to do this in C++?

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. actually i wanted to create a lot of constants which might change during the time of development so i would have to change it all the time. unfortunately it's not a great solution to do it manually

Comment: in this case the way I would do it I would put the enums in a separate file and create a generator (e.g. in Python) to create the enums based on your specifications.

Comment: What is "PAWN"? Is it the [Small-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-C)-derived [one](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pawn/info)?

Answer (score 4):

Not automatically, but you can specify each value manually:

```
enum X {
  a = 0x01,
  b = 0x02,
  c = 0x04
};
```

Comment: @sharptooth I don't see how you could do that with templates. I would be very interested if you would show a way.

Comment: @no, because I don't know any way how you can template an enum or the enum's values.

Comment: @sharptooth Support your statement with an example, please.

Comment: @sharptooth: Ehm, no.

Comment: I added a separate answer with example.

Comment: @binaryBaBa Added a separate answer

Answer (score 3):

You could automate this shifting process using [template metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming) (TMP):

```
template<int by>
struct OneShlBy {
    enum { Value = OneShlBy<by - 1>::Value << 1 };
};

template<>
struct OneShlBy<0> {
    enum { Value = 1 };
};

enum X {
    a = OneShlBy<0>::Value,
    b = OneShlBy<1>::Value,
    c = OneShlBy<2>::Value
};
```

Comment: If you have to apply OneShlBy on every constant, wouldn't it be easier to directly use the shift operator "a = 1, b = 1 << 1, ..." instead of your templates?

Comment: @neophoenix Would be easier until you plant a silly typo and then look for it for a while.

Answer (score 2):

One way, assuming [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), would be

```
constexpr int func(int x)
{
     return x << 1;
}

enum X
{
   a = 1,
   b = func(a),
   c = func(b)
};
```

The `func()` can then be used to implement any relationship you like between consecutive named values.

Before C++11, alternatives might include

```
enum X
{
   a = 1,
   b = a << 1,
   c = b << 1
};
```

or (with a macro)

```
#define func(x) x << 1
enum X
{
   a = 1,
   b = func(a),
   c = func(b)
};
#undef func
```

Answer (score 1):

One common approach for the particular example you give (enums which are essentially flags within a word) is to use two enums, one for the bit index and a second enum for the actual bit values:

```
enum {
   b_a,             // 0
   b_b,             // 1
   b_c,             // 2
   b_d,             // 3
};

enum {
   a = 1 << b_a,    // 1
   b = 1 << b_b,    // 2
   c = 1 << b_c     // 4
   d = 1 << b_d     // 8
};
```

It's not ideal, I know, but it avoids explicit literal constants. Some of the nastiness can be hidden with macros, which you may or may not consider a good thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you were doing works perfectly fine:

```
#include <iostream>

enum x {
   a = 0b001
 , b = 0b010
 , c = 0b100
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << x::a << '\n';
    std::cout << x::b << '\n';
    std::cout << x::c << '\n';
}
```

**Note:** this is only standard in [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14) where binary literals are introduced.

Otherwise you can use the shift operator to specify the bit position:

```
enum x {
      a = 1 << 0
    , b = 1 << 1
    , c = 1 << 2
};
```

Another possibility if you are looking to save some maintenance work is defining each `enum` in terms of previously defined `enums`:

```
enum x {
      a = 1
    , b = a << 1
    , c = b << 1
    , d = c << 1
    , e = d << 1
};
```

This means you can add an element in the middle relatively painlessly:

```
enum x {
      a = 1
    , b = a << 1
    , z = b << 1 // New element added
    , c = z << 1 // Only need to adjust one other
    , d = c << 1
    , e = d << 1
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately MS Visual Studio hasn't implemented the C++14 standard (binary literals) yet. Guess I'm gonna go with the shift operator even if I have to edit the whole enumerator if I remove or add a constant.

Comment: @neophoenix I added a method that makes maintaining long list enums a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

Stealing the great [idea of Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28809678/499359), there's a way to specify how to increment the value of an enum, this it isn't very automatic though, but as long as your enum have always the same fields you can do something like this:

```
template <typename T, T(*INC)(const T), T start = {}>
struct managed_enum
{
    enum
    {
        a = start,
        b = INC(a),
        c = INC(b),
    };
};
```

With this template you could do the following:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T shift_left(const T value) { return value << 1; }

using shifted = managed_enum<int, shift_left<int>, 1>;
```

Which results on the enum you're looking for ([see here](http://ideone.com/sCu1Sz)). Well, `shifted` isnt an enum but a struct, hope it doesn't matters.

Defining different increment functions, you can have different families of enums *automatically* increased, as long as all of them have only the three values of `managed_enum` (`a`, `b`, `c`):

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T shift_left(const T value) { return value << 1; }

template<typename T>
constexpr T increment(const T value) { return value + 1; }

template<typename T>
constexpr T bicrement(const T value) { return value + 2; }

using shifted   = managed_enum<int, shift_left<int>, 1>;
using increment = managed_enum<int, increment<int>>;
using bicrement = managed_enum<int, bicrement<int>>;
```